# Count Down Banner

Tags: javascript, banner-slider, count

I create a countdown banner on the homepage. I am storing  **from date and to date** in the system.xml.

I want to show the countdown between the dates From date to To date.

Can anybody guide me How can I do this?

I successfully create a static time. But want to the time between From and to Date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Java Script for countdown with the using of from date to To date and also add your logic as per your requirements.

Comment: can I go with phtml. I am getting the times values from the core_conifg_data and show in the frontend

Comment: yes @RanaZain you can get value from core_config_data using this line

$this->_scopeConfig ->getValue('your_configData_path',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)


and use value for your banner logic.